flutter force text to wrap in column
I have a widget that is a Column with two items, an Image and a Text widget underneath it. I want the text in the Text widget to be the same width as the image and to wrap if the text is too long. I put the widget in a Row and if there's more than one it works as intended, but if there's only one the text stays on a single line and the width of the widget expands to fit the full string of text instead of the width of the widget being limited to the width of the image. Code:
Semantics(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Image(
          imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Text(
          widget.text ?? '',
          softWrap: true,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 2,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),


You can use a LayoutBuilder to dynamically constrain the Text widget based on the size of the Image.
Semantics(
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Image(
            imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth, // Constrain to the width of the Column
            ),
            child: Text(
              widget.text ?? '',
              softWrap: true,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
)

